# How to sort keyword search results by hit frequency?

Tags: mysql, search, relevance

I've built a search index (two column table) which assigns single keywords to their content ID.

Now searching for single keywords works and is damn fast.

However, searching for multiple keywords like
`SELECT media_id, keyword FROM search_index WHERE keyword = 'b' OR keyword = 'a'` will return results in alphabetical keyword order (all hits on `'a'` first, then `'b'`).

I tried doing it with PHP on the results page, but that requires me to load a lot more data from the database than I want to display, to get an acceptable sorting. With that technique the script might even time out on a keywords that been assigned more frequently.

I also tried `GROUP BY` which seemed to group the result from the alphabetical order together to their single IDs.

Edit:
Lastly I found something like `SELECT DISTINCT media_id, keyword, COUNT(media_id) AS num FROM search_index GROUP BY media_id ORDER BY num DESC`, which works kinda well but is really slow.

So if i search for 'b' and 'a', I want the IDs with 'a' and 'b' first in the result.

So how can I tell MySQL to sort the output by the frequency of hits on one ID while still being damn fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out myself.

The fastest seems to be to do `SELECT media_id, keyword, COUNT(media_id) AS num WHERE ... GROUP BY media_id` and then going over the `num` field with a simple php-usort function.

```
function SortFrequency($a, $b)
{
     if ($a['num'] == $b['num']) return 0;
     return ($a['num'] > $b['num']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($results, 'SortFrequency');
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

SELECT *, CAST(keyword='a' AS SIGNED)+CAST(keyword='b' AS SIGNED) AS rank FROM search_index ORDER BY RANK DESC

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) which returns a relevancy score.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing me at what I try not to use with my search index solution here. Sure, I could put all the keywords in a `TEXT` field and fulltext search them, but did you ever feel the performance of something like that on a 300K+ row table? I guess not. (It takes up to a minute, where my index can provide search results within few milliseconds).

Comment: Sorry. Just trying to be helpful.

Comment: I appreciate help very much, I really do! But it's not leading anywhere when an answer defys any intention of the question.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not always possible to clearly discover the intent of questions. I posted another answer that might be more helpful :)